# Hide Sharepoint 2013 web parts until linked image is clicked

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2013 web part page that has 4 images and 4 webparts.  I want to hide the 4 web parts and only have them show based on click of the image above.  I.E.  Image 1 click shows WP 1, Image 2 click re-hides other wp(s) opened and only shows WP2, and so on.  See image below

[Images used and 4 WP's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOlsz.png)

Comment: you can use sharepoint desginer in that you will find the page code and you can make changes there as per you reuriments

Comment: I am unable to edit the code for the page it is only editable in the browser because it has a custom page layout.  I WAS able to hide the first WP that is under the Step 1 image by using the following code but now I need to be able to SHOW the webpart if a user clicks the image for step 1.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery.noConflict();
         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('#WebPartWPQ6').hide();
   //toggle the component with class msg_body
   jQuery('#WebPartWPQ6_ChromeTitle').click(function()
   {
     jQuery(this).next('#WebPartWPQ6').slideToggle(500);
   });
 });
</script>

Comment: Ok I am a bit closer, I added this code to my CWEP that has the table with my 4 images.  This code does not hide the list webpart by default it hides it once I click the first image.  I want it to work in reverse.  Any help?

Comment: src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript">
function hidepart()
 {
 $('#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').hide(); 
 }
</script> 
<table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-0">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-0" style="width: 25%; height: auto;">
            <a id="myLink" onclick="hidepart();return false;" href="#"><img alt="Step 1: Travel Recommendation" src="/sites/1VERC/travel/SiteAssets/Step1.png" style="margin: 0px;